# How to import an excel file directly in React?

Tags: reactjs

I am using react-excel-renderer to display an excel file and open it as table. It is working fine but I want to directly open the excel as table instead of having to choose the excel explicitly first. I don't want the "choose file" option that is coming from the input tag. Can you please suggest how I can directly import the excel from my local/root folder instead?

```
import {ExcelRenderer } from "react-excel-renderer";

export default function ExceltoGrid() {

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setFileObject(e.target.files[0]);
        }}
      />
      {fileObject &&
      <table>
        <thead className="row-heading">
          <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Effective Date</th>
            <th>Description</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        {data?.map((item) => (
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              <td>{item?.code}</td>
              <td>{item?.effDate}</td>
              <td>{item?.desc}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        ))}
      </table>}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In short, you can't because of browser security limitations.

A User must be able to select the file to be processed instead of it being automatically grabbed from their local system, think of the implications if we could look for certain files on a users system without their input.

I know this isn't great news to hear but its unfortunately a limitation for what you want to do.

Comment: I fixed by importing the excel that I wanted to display and send it as an api response.         xlsxFile('./Newfile.xlsx').then((rows) => res.send(rows))

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get it via an API call.
The API call should be made on the page load.